# jQuery - get array values and use it one by one

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'am trying to remove all selected classes with all values of an array , but i can't do it(i'am deleting only the first of array), what is the way to solve that ? Below you can find what i was trying to do.

HTML:

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="red">red</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="green">green</input><br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="blue">blue</input><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete selected colors"></input><br><br/>
        <div class="thumbnailas">
            <img class="red">
            <img class="green">
            <img class="blue">
        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
            var allVals = [];
            var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
                result.each(function() {
                    allVals.push($(this).val())
                });
                $('.'+ allVals).hide();
            });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h6bofqae/3/

Comment: is this what you want https://jsfiddle.net/db93v4dy/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

Either:

a) Loop through your `allVals` array are hide each element based on the class in there.

Instead of `$('.'+ allVals).hide();`, you'll want:

```
allVals.forEach(function(class) {
    $('.' + class).hide();
});
```

b) Forget the array, just loop through each selected checkbox and find elements based on the value.

```
var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    result.each(function() {
        $('.'+ $(this).val()).hide();
    });
});
```

c) If you really want to use an array and hide the elements in a single statement (without looping again), you can use `Array.join`.

```
$('.' + allVals.join(',.')).hide();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h6bofqae/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without using arrays. JavaScript would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        result.each(function() {
            $('.'+ $(this).val()).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h6bofqae/5/

If you need to use an array, then you can iterate through allVals array like this:

```
for (color of allVals) {
    $('.'+color).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove them directly, don't need to create an array, the jquery code is like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {    
    var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        result.each(function() {
            $('.' + $(this).val()).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your jquery code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
        var result = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
            result.each(function() {
                $('.'+ $(this).val()).hide();
            });

        });
});
```